# plpgsql procedure: how to add auto_increment field to a query

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I have the following plpgsql procedure/function, where I am trying to get a set of records with an Auto_increment value. I have made up the field "position" to store the autoincrement, and I guess that is wrong, but I don't know how to work out this query where I want to add a new calculated field. I think my intention is clear. Does anyone could help me?, please!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pra2.GetRankingOfPilots(IN sea pra2.season.name%type)
RETURNS setof RECORD AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    r RECORD;
    fila integer;
BEGIN
    fila:=0;
    FOR r IN SELECT  
          position,
          driver.name driver, 
          constructor.name constructor,
          season.name season,
          CAST(sum(runs.points) AS int) totalpuntos
        FROM 
          pra2.hired hired
        INNER JOIN pra2.constructor on  hired.name_constructor = pra2.constructor.name
        INNER JOIN pra2.driver on hired.num_driver = pra2.driver.num
        INNER JOIN pra2.runs on pra2.driver.num=pra2.runs.num_driver
        INNER JOIN pra2.race on pra2.runs.name_race=pra2.race.name AND pra2.runs.season_fk=pra2.race.season_fk AND pra2.runs.season_fk=pra2.race.season_fk
        INNER JOIN pra2.season on hired.name_season=pra2.season.name AND pra2.race.season_fk=pra2.season.name
        WHERE
            pra2.season.name=sea
        GROUP BY
            season,driver,constructor
        ORDER BY
            TotalPuntos Desc
    LOOP
        fila:=fila+1;
        r.posicion:=fila;
        RETURN NEXT r;
    END LOOP;
RETURN;
END; 
$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
SELECT  
          row_number() over () position,
          driver.name driver, 
          constructor.name constructor,
          season.name season,
          CAST(sum(runs.points) AS int) totalpuntos
        FROM 
          pra2.hired hired
        INNER JOIN pra2.constructor on  hired.name_constructor = pra2.constructor.name
        INNER JOIN pra2.driver on hired.num_driver = pra2.driver.num
        INNER JOIN pra2.runs on pra2.driver.num=pra2.runs.num_driver
        INNER JOIN pra2.race on pra2.runs.name_race=pra2.race.name AND pra2.runs.season_fk=pra2.race.season_fk AND pra2.runs.season_fk=pra2.race.season_fk
        INNER JOIN pra2.season on hired.name_season=pra2.season.name AND pra2.race.season_fk=pra2.season.name
        WHERE
            pra2.season.name=sea
        GROUP BY
            season,driver,constructor
        ORDER BY
            TotalPuntos Desc
```

Comment: I get the error of types, saying that I cannot change the return type of created function

Comment: drop it and create again

Comment: or cast bigint to whatever it was before